# Is there any working example of "pytap" TAP emitter for Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, tap

if we look at like in example 3:

```
#TEST SOME STUFF
from TAP.Simple import *

plan(3)

def in_between(value, bottom, top, msg):
    ret = ok(((bottom = value) and (value = top)), msg)
    if (not ret):
        diag("value %s is not between %s and %s" % (value, bottom, top))
    return ret

in_between(5, 3, 10, "5 is OK.")

in_between(5.5, 5, 6, "5[2] is OK.")

# This will fail.
in_between(1, 20, 30, "1 is in range.")
```

I am trying to see how i can use this with real Python code

note: the ret = ok statement has <= and => instead of just = , the code was not getting displayed so i took them out, and i am not sure how to escape them

Here is an example that can be used as a source.

```
'''Convert to and from Roman numerals

This program is part of 'Dive Into Python 3', a free Python book for
experienced programmers.  Visit http://diveintopython3.ep.io/ for the
latest version. - old website http://diveintopython3.org/ is not available anymore.
'''

roman_numeral_map = (('M',  1000),
                     ('CM', 900),
                     ('D',  500),
                     ('CD', 400),
                     ('C',  100),
                     ('XC', 90),
                     ('L',  50),
                     ('XL', 40),
                     ('X',  10),
                     ('IX', 9),
                     ('V',  5),
                     ('IV', 4),
                     ('I',  1))

def to_roman(n):
    '''convert integer to Roman numeral'''
    result = ''
    for numeral, integer in roman_numeral_map:
        while n >= integer:
            result += numeral
            n -= integer
    return result

# Copyright (c) 2009, Mark Pilgrim, All rights reserved.
# 
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
# are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
# 
# * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
#   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
# * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
#   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
#   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
# 
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS 'AS IS'
# AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
# ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
# LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
# CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
# SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
# INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
# CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
# ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
# POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK , i figured it out myself, by looking at perl's TAP examples, and transposing it to fit Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import TAP

ok = TAP.Builder.create(3).ok
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"
ok(hello_world() ==  "Hello, World!", "First Test")
ok(hello_world() is  "Hello, World!", "Second Test")
ok(isinstance(hello_world(),str), "Third Test")
```

Explanation:

1. `import TAP` once you have installed it on your host
2. `ok = TAP.Builder.create(3).ok`: 3 means you plan 3 tests, the rest just follow without questions
3. First Test uses "code" then condition (`==`) and then expected result

The same goes for `is`, or `isinstance()`

Comment: So, you transposed the Perl-like example to [PyTap](http://git.codesimply.com/?p=PyTAP.git) (which at least is publicly available).